# API для создания зашифрованных контейнеров

Tags: api, шифрование

Ранее я пользовался программой TrueCrypt, которая позволяет создавать зашифрованные контейнеры, которые в последствии можно было монтировать в TrueCrypt в виде образов и записывать в них файлы.

Однако, проблема в том, что данный софт не имеет никакого API, т.е нельзя с ним взаимодействовать из других программ...

Подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь схожие программки, но с API, а еще лучше совместимые с контейнерами TrueCrypt.